# How to use main args[] to call methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, args

I am wondering if there is any way of calling a class function by using main args[] instead of having like the following:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String choice="";
    System.in(choice);

    if (choice.contains("1"))
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.function();
    }
    else
    {
        Item2 item2 = new Item2();
        item2.function2();
     }


   }

}
```

And have something like:

```
-a calls the x function
-b calls the y function
```

Comment: `if(args[0].equals("a"))`?

Comment: Yes there is a way...Just call your program passing in the `args` and check if the parameter is `a` or `b` then call the method just like you are doing.

Comment: Have a look at [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) which should make implementing that easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a main method `args` is an array containing the passed arguments to your program, so you can access its elements by index like any other Java array.

This is what you need to do:

```
if (args[0].contains("a")){
    Item item = new Item();
    item.function();
}
else if(args[0].contains("b")){
    Item2 item2 = new Item2();
    item2.function2();
}
```

Comment: i mean in case you need to enter one more argument

Comment: you can use `args[1]`for the second argument, you access each argument by its index.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String choice=args[0];
    if (choice.equals("a")) {
        Item item =mFinal.new Item();
        item.function(); 
    }else{
        Item2 item2 =mFinal.new Item2();
        item2.function2();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to need to reference something about 2-D arrays on my textbook when I came across this sentence which blew my mind!

> It  is  not  required  that  the  name  of main’s  parameter  array 
>   be args.  You  can name it anything you wish. It is a standard convention, 
>   however, for the name args to be used.

I tried it ot and it's true. Maybe this is common knowledge, but I had no idea. Don't believe me? Try it!

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseString {
   public static void main(String[] gafuydqaFUYQ) {

    String userString;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence and I will reverse in.");
    userString = input.nextLine();

    String a[] = userString.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

}